# Display Module Wrapper link in content area of Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I added a module (wrapper) that displays an image. The image is linked to another webpage.

It is in a sidebar position and when it is clicked, the page loads in the same position as the image (as it should).

However, is it possible to have the linked page load in the main page or content area of Joomla instead of the module position?

(Joomla 2.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

1. You can use the current module you have and embed it in an article using `{loadposition xxx}`
2. Create a menu item and set the type to "wrapper".

Comment: Thanks. 1. I have been attempting {loadposition xxx} but it only shows this: {loadposition featuredprop} I created the unique position name for the module and have the Content Load Modules plugin enabled.

2. Can I still use the image as a menu item?

Comment: you dont need the "Content Load Modules" plugin for {loadposition xxx} to work. It comes standard with Joomla. The image can't be an actualy menu item but you can just give it link, so that it links to a page with a wrapper.

Comment: I need it to show as an image on the home page in a sidebar position - real estate featured property. I will keep working on the loadposition. Thanks.

Comment: if you provide a link you your site so I can have a look, that might be easier.

Comment: Fixed it :) The {loadposition xxx} was wrapped in code tags. Removed and all is well. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Would never have thought of that, but glad you gt it fixed.